# Copy between two DB SQLITE

Tags: c#

I have two DB:

**Country1.sqlite**, which is full, and **Country2.sqlite**, which is empty.

I want to copy the tables of Country1.sqlite in Country2.sqlite using C#. 
How can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you already try? You can use sqlite-net nuget package to get access to the sqlite db from C# code. After this you need to load everything in memory from `Country1.sqlite` and write this into `Country2.sqlite`

Comment: Why not just copy the entire file?